# Java - Trying to extract url from email

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jakarta-mail, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to extract an url from email.

I'm using selenium webdriver and I want to check through the test the email account to verify email was sent.

I managed to get to the email account and I did a few testings with it but when trying to use it in my automation it fails with this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.newIMAPMessage(IMAPFolder.java:1395)
at com.sun.mail.imap.MessageCache.getMessage(MessageCache.java:146)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.getMessages(IMAPFolder.java:1860)
at com.YakirSaadia.Tools.EmailVerification.getUrlFromEmail(EmailVerification.java:144)
at com.YakirSaadia.Tools.EmailVerification.runTest(EmailVerification.java:45)
at com.YakirSaadia.VendorTests.RegisterNewComp.registerNewCompany(RegisterNewComp.java:55)
at com.YakirSaadia.VendorTests.RegisterNewComp.runTest(RegisterNewComp.java:26)
at com.YakirSaadia.Vendor.vendorTests(Vendor.java:36)
at com.YakirSaadia.Main.main(Main.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataHandler
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
... 9 more
```

If someone could help me it would be great!

**Edit:**

Couldn't find any other post that answers my questions.
I dont need to send the url or something like that, I need to extract it to use it in my automation testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `activation.jar` is not in your classpath when you run your test. From the JavaMail readme:

> ### Requirements
>
> Note that the JavaMail API requires the JavaBeans(TM) Activation
>   Framework package to be installed as well if you're using JDK 1.5.
>   Download the latest version of the JavaBeans Activation Framework from
>
> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-jsp-136939.html
>
> and install it in a suitable location.